# Using the "People" feature of Google Photos to populate Google Contacts photos

Tags: google-contacts, google-photos

I have recently discovered the *People* feature of Google Photos to group photos of the same person together in an album. Once all your photos have been grouped, you can tell Google who the person is (it pulls the names of your contacts to assign to the groups). However, there seems to be no way to then link this photo group back to your contacts - it seems to be a one way affair.

Has anyone managed to do this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I want this to be an automated process; in that if a particular person in my contact list has a Google Photos group associated to them, thier contact photo should be automatically set.

Comment: If you have an Android phone, it's easy. I don't see a way to do it (easily) from the web, though.

Comment: @ale If it's so easy, would you mind sharing/answering?

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I'd avoided it as this is Web Apps.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible. Let us hope that Google implements this feature soon.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Android device with a relatively recent version of Android (and Contacts and Photos) it's really easy to choose a photo and make it the photo for the contact. (It won't link the group of photos, though.)

Go into Google Photos and find the photo you want to use. Tap the overflow menu (three vertical dots) in the upper right and tap "Use as". You have the option to use the photo as your wallpaper or as a contact photo. Tap "Contact photo", then choose the contact for which you want to use the photo.

Comment: Ah right I see what you meant now. I perhaps wasn't completely clear in my request. I want to automate this function so I don't have to run through all of my contacts individually - if a particular contact has a photo group within Google Photos, their contact photo should be automatically set. I'll update my question for clarity. Thanks anyway

Comment: Good to know there's a way that doesn't involve wading through recent photos on the Web. Wish the web UI had this feature.