# Is it Possible to Sync Google Contacts Photos with Google Photos People?

Tags: google-contacts, google-photos

It's will be awesome if anyone has guide to do this? Sync Google Contacts Photos with Google Photos People with latest or Photos that we choose as favorited photos

Comment: Are you asking the opposite of [Using the "People" feature of Google Photos to populate Google Contacts photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105311/197614)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.